# how to get occupied storage info of objects in apex

Tags: api, storage-limit, storage

[image: this image is from user storage and I want to access it object wise to create a chart]

this image is from user storage and I want to access it object wise to create a chart from apex code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as of now(v50.0).

Please see the idea raised for the same -
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006zM9AAI

However, if you need it on urgent basis, you can try one workaround(not trustworthy/recommended until absolutely necessary).

In Salesforce every record is of approx. 2KB(this may vary for other cases - [Help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318951&type=1&mode=1) ), so you can calculate the sizing based on count of each type.

Example - `[SELECT count() FROM Account]` can give you  1000 count and you can calculate with 2Kb which is 2000KB (2000/1024 MB).

Comment: how to get the count of the record of every object in one apex call

Comment: you can use schema calls like used here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100668/retrieve-api-names-of-all-object-in-salesforce-org-using-soql/100669

Comment: what is rest api soql limit

Comment: standard SOQL limit would be there 50K (with query call) . You can cross check on rest api guide.